# Iphone 5 full screen size

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have included a launch image named: Default-568h@2x.png (640x1136) in the bundle.  But the iPhone 5 still has that two vertical black bar on both right and left side in landscape mode.  If I removed all launch images from the Images.xcassets then it shows up with full screen.

What did I do wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to actually add a launch image in the "R4" (Retina 4 inch) image well. It seems that you've only added a launch image for the "2x" (Retina 3.5 inch), and if iOS if Xcode isn't pointed towards a 4 inch default image, the app will remain in 3.5 inch mode.

Comment: That was it.  Do you know why the launch image show up for iPad but not iPhone when app launched?