# Launch Image not shown on iOS7 iPhone after using asset catalog

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode5, asset-catalog

I set the requested size PNG for my app asset catalog. 
I tested both simulator and devices. 
The launch images were shown on

- iPad Retina iOS7
- iPod 5th gen iOS6.1
- iPhone4S iOS6.1

But not shown on

- iPhone5S iOS7 both my device and simulator

The first image is the asset catalog configuration and the second image is name of PNG files used in the asset catalog.

I am wondering if I need further setting for it work.
I have researched around the similar issues but none were the same here...

Thank you for reading and any information is much appreciated.

[PNG images used in Asset category](http://gyazo.com/ceb687a013e37082c6ac87c9f369dabe)

[Launchimage asset catalog](http://gyazo.com/697563ce67019cce332b57ab7ece8fd7)

Comment: Does not work on 3.5inch/iOS7 simulator. In a word and rephrase, iPhone on iOS7, the launch image by asset catalog is not working on my configuration.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in Xcode if yours was landscape image.  Try this fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110583/iphone-landscape-only-no-launch-image-for-ios7-r4-image-asset

Comment: Thanks, I tried but the result is worse for me. Not only black launch image shown but the both sides of 4 inch screen cut and gives 3.5 inch view throughout the all app experience...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814646/iphone-5-full-screen-size

Comment: Thanks, still not shown. Unchecked iOS7 and added the all assets requested. This seems to be a bug in xcode, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, make sure the image is saved with the normal settings, not compressed or interlaced when saved. For example, in Photoshop when you save the PNG launch image choose "None" for both Compression & Interlace options. And for JPEG, make sure it's not progressive and select "Baseline ("Standard")" in format options. It worked for me. Make sure to clean & build after adding the new pictures. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I noticed my app was starting with no launch image and when it displayed the initial view controller it was in landscape mode even though the app supported portrait and I was holding the phone that way. The app was previously landscape only so I added portrait later. I noticed in "Supported interface orientations" the landscape options were first, so I thought maybe that order had something to do with why the app started that way. I removed the whole key then went and re-checked all the orientations starting with "Portrait". My app started showing the launch image and started in portrait mode. I also noticed that in Attribute inspector for the LaunchImage asset collection iPhone doesn't have landscape checkboxes so I guess if you're app is starting in landscape mode, it has no image to work with.

Side note: Look out for  "Initial interface orientation" set to landscape too.

Comment: no way! I am developing a landscape-only app as well. When the portrait mode is not supported in the info.plist, the launch image does not show, but there is indeed no landscape LaunchImage for iPhone. Thumbs up for xcode!